# WP_query category__in not working, only pulls from first category

Tags: wp-query, categories, query, get-posts

I wrote a WP_query and the behaviour is weird.
I tried almost everything but that's not working. I found a solution but i try to understand.

The following queries always returns posts from the first caregory (id : 15, slug : slug1).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category__in'    => array(15, 17),
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$items = $query->get_posts();
```

OR

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat'    => '15,17',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$items = $query->get_posts();
```

OR

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name'    => 'slug1,slug2',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$items = $query->get_posts();
```

OR

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array(15,17),
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$items = $query->get_posts();
```

The solution was to use query_post($args) instead of WP_query->get_posts()

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category__in'    => array(15, 17),
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);

$items = get_posts($args);
```

Can you tell me where i'm wrong ?

Comment: `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` but does not apply query filters by default. If you are getting different results from each, you have a query filter which is not correctly targeted.

Comment: I do not have any filters (maybe in plugins), but you told me what I want.

Comment: I have this identical issue and it occurs on a vanilla 4.9.8 too. Tested with two categories, it occurred 100% of the times if the categories are on different branches or if a child is supplied before its parent in the array. The result was as expected only when I supplied the array as (<parent>,<child>). There is clearly some kind of bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo)'s answer, I found another workaround that works and i'm more confortable with it.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category__in'    => array(15, 17),
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);

$query = new WP_Query();
$items = $query->query($args);
```

Comment: How you fix that? I have same problem...

Comment: I fixed by using 

$query = new WP_Query();
$items = $query->query($args);

instead of 

$items = get_posts($args);